# Elasticsearch query for multiple fields terms and multile filelds must not match query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

My requirement is below:

1. I need to use multiple fields for must_not match conditions
2. I need to use multiple fields in terms query

When I run the below query, Getting the following error for Must_not

> "reason": "[match] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [app_rating] and [satisfaction_rating]"

And for the Terms multiple fields also getting the error.

> "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] under [should], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [MyBuckets]",

How can I correct the query?

```
  "size":0,
  "_source":["comments.keyword"],
    "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match":{"source.keyword": "ONA"}}
      
      ],
    "must_not":[
      
      {"match":{"app_rating":"0","satisfaction_rating":"0","usability_rating": "0"}}
      ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
  "MyBuckets": {
    "should":[{
    "terms": {
      "fields": ["comments.keyword"]
    }
    },
    {
      "terms":{
        "fields": ["app_rating"]
      }
    },
    {
      "terms":{
        "fields": ["satisfaction_rating"]
      }
    },
    {
      "terms":{
        "fields": ["usability_rating"]
      }
      
    }
    ],
      "order":{
        "_count": "desc"
      },
      "size": "10"

}
}
}

** Below is the sample Mapping details**
'''{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "Id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
}
        }
      },
      "app_rating": {
        "type": "long"
      },
"comments": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
"conversation_rating": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
}
        }
      },
      "satisfaction_rating": {
        "type": "long"
      },
"source": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
"timestamp": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "usability_rating": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your index mapping and sample docs, so that I can provide the working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple fields in a single `must_not` clause, so you have to add multiple `must_not` clause also you are trying to use terms aggregations on various terms and your syntax is not correct which is causing the exception.

**can you provide your index mapping and sample docs, so that I can provide the working example.**

Comment: **GET logstash-sdc-abt-memberfeedback/_search?**  Can you please modify my query and re share it herewith will be more helpful. I am not that much familiar in Elastic search. Please support me.

Comment: Added the sample data herewith. Please check above

Comment: Dear Team, Can someone please help  me with the my concern. I need to use 3 fields must not match & 3 fields for terms query. I am stuck in the query. Please correct my query and help me on this.

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 you didn't provide the required info which I asked in comment of question.

Comment: Please check the above query for the sample mapping docs. I have mentioned below the main query

Comment: Dear Team, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Dear Team, As requested I have shared the index mapping details below my original query. Request you to kindly check the mapping and modify my query and share